# JSON undefined data in a dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have three dropdowns called Platform, Tasktype and Component which is dependent on each other. I have figured out until the second dropdown to get relevant data however the third dropdown gets undefined.

**See working demo below.**

http://plnkr.co/tFZhcTm1XeqK3NoHdG4z

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
var platforms;
var tasktypes;
var compos;
var jsonData;


$.getJSON('tasks.json', function(result) {
jsonData = result;

$.each(result, function(i, platform) {
platforms += "<option value='" +
  platform.name +
  "'>" +
  platform.name +
  "</option>";
});
$('#platform').html(platforms);
}); 

$("#platform").change(function (){
var idx = $("#platform").prop('selectedIndex');
var platforms = jsonData[idx].task;

tasktypes = "";
for (i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
  tasktypes += "<option value='" +
    platforms[i].taskname +
    "'>" +
    platforms[i].taskname +
    "</option>";
};
$('#taskname').html(tasktypes);
});


$("#taskname").change(function (){
var idc = $("#taskname").prop('selectedIndex');
var tasktypes = jsonData[idc].task;

compos = "";
for (i = 0; i < tasktypes.length; i++) {
  compos += "<option value='" +
    tasktypes[i].componentname +
    "'>" +
    tasktypes[i].componentname +
    "</option>";
};
$('#components').html(compos);
});  
});
```

I want to get relevant component names once platform and task type is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#taskname").change(function (){
    var idc = $("#taskname").prop('selectedIndex');
    var tasktypes = jsonData[idc].task;

console.log(tasktypes); // include and see what is coming over here in console 

    compos = "";
    for (i = 0; i < tasktypes.length; i++) {

console.log(tasktypes[i]); // include and see what is coming over here in console  

      compos += "<option value='" +
        tasktypes[i].componentname +
        "'>" +
        tasktypes[i].componentname +
        "</option>";
    };
    $('#components').html(compos);
    });  
    });
```

some data  is missing somewhere or script doesnt understand what is coming that what happens i believe

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' This is what I got

Comment: okay that is may ve  some syntax error include a }  and check what do u obtain in console.log(tasktypes);

Comment: ReferenceError: tasktypes is not defined

Comment: absolute beginner to jquery. appreciate if you could help a bit more. I think the problem is with Json selector here. var tasktypes = jsonData[idc].task; but can't figure out a way to solve this.

Comment: have a look in console.log(platforms) in platform.change function ,  u have already achieved it in here ! or see what comes in jsonData console.log(jsonData)

Comment: ar tasktypes = jsonData[idc].task; yes you are absolutely correct now try solve the issue in  jsonData[idc].task; console.log(jsonData) will help you

Comment: will you able to edit the plunker link ? Struggle is real